# Undefined Reference c++ lost

Tags: c++, reference, undefined

```
#include "assert.h"; // for some reason assert wouldn't work on my compiler without this
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>   // This is helpful for inputting values. Otherwise, funny stuff happens


using namespace std;


class Product
{
public:

    Product();
    Product(string the_name, int the_price, int number_of);

    string return_name();
    void reduce_amount();
    void print_data() const;

private:
    string prod_name; // name of your product
    int price_in_cents; // it's price in cents
    int amount; // the number of the product that you have
};

Product::Product()
{

    prod_name = "NULL_NAME: NEED DATA";
    price_in_cents = 0;
}

Product::Product(string the_name, int the_price, int number_of)
{
    assert(the_price>0);
    assert(number_of>0);
    assert(number_of<21);
    assert(prod_name !="NULL_NAME: NEED DATA");
    prod_name = the_name;
    price_in_cents = the_price;
    amount = number_of;
}

void Product::print_data() const
{
    cout<<prod_name << endl;
    cout<<"The price in cents is: " <<price_in_cents<< endl;
    cout<< "Amount left: " << " " << amount << endl;
}

void Product::reduce_amount()
{
    amount = amount -1;
}


string Product::return_name()
{
    return prod_name;
}

class Vending_Machine
{
public:

    Vending_Machine();
    void empty_coins();
    void print_vend_stats();
    void add_product();
    Product buy_product();
private:
    int income_in_cents;

    Product product1();
    Product product2();
    Product product3();
    Product product4();
    Product product5();
};

void Vending_Machine::empty_coins()
{
    cout << "The total amount of money earned today is " << income_in_cents << " cents" << endl;
    income_in_cents = 0;
    cout << "All the coins have been withdrawn. The balance is now zero." <<     endl;
}

void Vending_Machine::print_vend_stats()
{

    cout<< "Total income thus far: " << income_in_cents << endl;

    if (product1().return_name() != "NULL_NAME: NEED DATA")
    {
        //stuff happens
    }
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

So, I'm not sure if I did all the identation correctly, but I'm having a problem with the boolean statement in vending machine print_vend_stats() function. It's saying I am making an undefined fereence to product1(). What does this mean?

Comment: Well, where do you *define* `product1`? All I see is a *declaration*, as a *function*. Maybe you are supposed to declare `protuct1` etc. as an *object*, i.e. `Product product1;`?

Comment: Oh and regarding [`assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert), it's a *preprocessor macro* defined in the `<cassert>` header file.

Comment: It's defined in the datafields of vending_machine, I thought. Since it's a member function I thought it would automatically call by reference to product1().

Comment: So where is an instance of Vending_Machine created?

Comment: No, those are member function *declarations* and not definitions. A function definition would be the function wiht the actual implementation (function body). Like when you do e.g. `void Vending_Machine::empty_coins() { ... }`, *that's* a definition.

Comment: member function definitions in the private datafields? I'm confused :/ Please explain more, I am mucho noob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare

```
Product product1();
```

you declare a member *function*, the parentheses is what makes it a function.

If you drop the parentheses

```
Product product1;
```

you declare a member *variable*, an actual instance of the `Product` class.

---

Another example, you wouldn't write e.g.

```
int income_in_cents();
```

do declare `income_in_cents` as a variable, now would you?

It doesn't matter if the type is a primitive type like `int`, or a class like `Product`, Member variables are declared like normal variables like you do anywhere else.

Comment: HERP DERP! Erm frerm deprmernistern!!! I see what I did wrong. I thought by adding the parenthesis that I was telling it to use the default constructor. I see now. Thanks bro. You're a lifesaver. I tried to upvote you but still don't have enough points.

Comment: @MadisonC.Brewer Well you should still be able to accept my answer, I think :) You do that by clicking the little check mark ✔ next to my answer.

Comment: "I thought by adding the parenthesis that I was telling it to use the default constructor"... wait until you see the **most vexing parse**.